# why tablets start up when connect to charger while laptops do not

Tags: laptop, android, tablet

I think any Android tablet will start up when it connected to its charger .. Why that .. and why laptops do not act the same ?! one more thing can I turn off the tablet and keep it connect to charger ?

Comment: No tablets I've seen turn on when "plugged in", most will show a "charging" image or animation, but it's not a full turn-on boot or anything. Turn your tablet off while it's charging and find out.

Comment: If the tablet is off and I connect it to charger it will turn on .. like I press "ON" button without pressing it !
The laptop dose not !
Why ?

Comment: Some laptops you can setup this way in BIOS. It always depends what the Manufacturer of the device decides to implement. With start up you mean like - it was powered off and it powers on or like - the screen turns on? My table if powered off will not power on when connected (except teh battery charging icon as @Xen2050 mentioned) but will light up if powered on and then connected to charger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my androids phones and tables connecting the charger never turn on (from off state) the systems, like laptops.  But on new phones and tables, plugging the charge will wake up the systems, if they were only suspended.

Why?  On android the wake up is very cheap, and apps are supposed not to wake up or doing jobs without needs. Instead, on laptops wake up require much more power and CPU, and programs can forbid the laptop to sleep again (in short time).  This is due mainly to programs that are not designed with quick sleeps and wake ups. In Android and iOS this is (and was) a requirement to programs from the beginning.

Note: opening and closing the lid is an easy what to wake up laptop. (tablets doesn't have lids by default).

Note: I setup all my desktops with a similar way: when I turn on electricity on my power strip, monitors, desktop and peripherals will power on automatically.